# How to check the transform rotate with if in js

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to check the transform rotate in if with java script?

> getComputedstyle

Answer (score 0):

Here an Example to get the property of transform...
The issue for this is, that you don't get something like 30deg as return from transform either you get a matrix...
this can be transformed back to your deg -> which i think u wanna know in the end ;)

[further information about matrix and calculation](https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/)

[here](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html) an online calculator for getting degree's out of a matrix

```js
var rotateStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.rotate'), null);

alert(rotateStyle.transform);
```

```css
.rotate {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="rotate">&lsaquo;3</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In http://jsfiddle.net/ax5nM/108/ a class `box` is used – until now for checking for `translateX`

```
var t=$(".box").css('transform').split(/[()]/)[1].split(',');
```

but also makes the properties of the matrix accessible.

some examples what the matrix stands for is to be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_matrix